# Is using the present perfect old fashioned?

Tags: american-english, present-perfect, transatlantic-differences, singapore-english

I was talking to a Singaporean (English is her native language. I think, closer to American rather than British) friend.

I learned in English class that you can use present perfect when there is a connection with present. So the discussion was something like that. I was trying to use present perfect correctly.

> A: Have you been to French class today?
>
> B: Yes I have. I went this morning.

But she told me it's an old fashion way of using present perfect. And no one uses it like that, at least not in the US and Singapore.
She would use past simple there.

> A: Did You go to French class today?

Is it wrong to use the present perfect here or do I look stupid if I use it?

Comment: One American's perspective: If there's only one French class held each day, you should use the simple past. If going to French class is something you have several opportunities to do each day (which one presumes is the case here from the answer), the present perfect is better.

Comment: @PeterShor There is one french class every week it was the evening when i asked.

Comment: Singapore English - Singlish - is a poor guide to correct useage. You can trust me on this: I live there.

Comment: The difference is that the perfect comments on a stretch of time, while the simple past need not. So words like _yet_ or _already_ can get used more easily with the perfect (_have you been there yet, he's already been there_). With an event that's regular and repetitive like a class, the potential differences between the two constructions are largely neutralized, and it doesn't make any difference which one gets used. This happens a lot; there's a great deal of overlapping redundancy and tolerance for ambiguity in natural language.

Comment: @jasper Loy ~ that depends on whether you accept the 'anything goes' theory of language or not. I don't for two reasons. One is where do you draw the line? Do you tell a student who is constructing ungrammatical sentences that they are OK, just variants? The second is that if you don't maintain a standard and just accept any 'variant', you defeat the purpose of the language as variants become unintelligible - as Singlish frequently is to other English speakers. American or Australian English is a variant. Singlish is closer to a creole as it imports non-English structures.

Comment: @John Lawler: Yes, words like *yet* and *already* (which have close associations with ***now***) work better with the perfect. And sometimes those words *don't* work so well with the past simple (which I suppose I'll have to accept *"Did you go"* is an example of). But there's nothing wrong with *"Did you buy that today?"*, so in constructions where the time-frame being queried is explicitly specified as very recent, I see no meaningful difference arising from the choice of tense. Except that *"Have you bought that today?"* is a less-likely construction in any case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will "Present Perfect vs. Past Tense" cases be affected by culture?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/when-will-present-perfect-vs-past-tense-cases-be-affected-by-culture)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It wouldn't be wrong to say "Did you go to French Class today?", nor would it make you look stupid. Your friend is wrong though. There is nothing old-fashioned about using a perfect tense where a perfect tense is needed.

In your example, it would depend on the circumstances. "Did you go to French class today?" is seeking information and nothing more. "Have you been to French class today?" is important in the present - maybe you want to know what you have missed, or help with homework.

Comment: You seem to be saying there's some difference in meaning/nuance between *"Have you been to work today?"* and *"Did you go to work today?"*. I think there is no meaningful distinction to be made.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, how about "I've been to the dentist today. My teeth look so white!" vs. "I went to the dentist today. Had to to take the morning off work."

Comment: cf. Swan 2005, "Did Ann phone you today?" (you expected Ann to phone you at a particular time) vs. "Has Ann phoned you today?" (no such implication).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, past simple is for finished 'dead' actions. Present perfect is for 'live' actions that are either still happening, have present consequences, or are still relevant. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Alex B.,Roaring Fish: My position (which I think is reflected by John Lawler in his comment to the Q) is that in OP's construction *have/did* are simply alternative ways of building an interrogative. I think that distinction from Swan is just so much pedantic tosh - since most people don't recognise or implement it, the point means nothing. Nor is it relevant to quote *other* constructions where using past simple or present perfect may make a difference; in OP's case there simply is no difference in nuance.

Comment: I can see a difference. I would use "have you been..." if I had an ulterior motive for asking, and "did you..." if it were mere curiosity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I just wanted to see how you'd interpret those examples. I quoted Swan to show you that some speakers make that distinction. Others don't. I see no problem there. In most cases acceptability is contextual; it also depends on your age, education, gender, where you've lived etc. - you know what I mean.

Comment: @Roaring Fish: If that were a generally-acknowledged distinction, don't you think smart people would always use *did*, to conceal the fact they had an ulterior motive for asking? It's true *"Have you been drinking alcohol?"* is almost invariably "accusatory", whereas *"Did you drink alcohol?"* can be merely asking in a neutral way. But these are nothing to do with OP's case unless we assume *going to French class* is a euphemism for some morally questionable act.

Comment: Why should an ulterior motive always be bad? Maybe I just want to copy some homework answers. The central point is that it has relevance now, where "did you go... " hasn't.

Comment: @Roaring Fish: You've lost me there. Asking a question with an *"ulterior motive"* means you have some *secret, covert* reason for asking. Such as when a suspect claims he spent the afternoon in a cinema when a murder was committed across town. Cop asks what movie he saw, with the ulterior motive of breaking the alibi if the suspect can't come up with the name of the movie that was showing at the time. It could hardly apply to asking questions to help with your homework.

Comment: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/208657?redirectedFrom=ulterior#eid.   Ulterior is unstated, beyond the immediate discussion, but does not have to be the sinister, evil intent you ascribe to it.

Comment: @Roaring Fish: I never actually said that *ulterior* has any sinister, evil, or otherwise negative connotations. It most assuredly does, but I didn't say so - in which case I can only assume if you think I *did*, it's because you recognise those connotations yourself. All I said was that if you have an ulterior motive (by definition, something you wish to conceal) you wouldn't announce that fact by using a form of words generally recognised as indicative of a concealed motive.

Comment: "Asking a question with an "ulterior motive" means you have some secret, covert reason for asking."?

Answer (score 9):

You are right and your friend is wrong.

For instance, look at the following sentences and at the explanations below to understand the difference between present perfect and past simple:

> (a) Past simple: I lived in Florence for five years (... but I do not
>   live there anymore.)
>
> (b) Present perfect: I have lived in Florence for five years (... and I
>   still live there now.)
>
> (c) Past simple: I broke my glasses ... (but it does not matter. I
>   repaired them.)
>
> (d) Present perfect: I have broken my glasses ... (and so I can't see
>   properly now.)

You probably learned the difference between (a) and (b) years ago: one of the differences between *past simple* and *past perfect* is the 'time' of the verb, i.e. when it happened. The difference between (c) and (d) is harder to understand.

In (c) and (d), 'time', i.e. when the verb happened, is not really what separates the two sentences; it is possible that both (c) and (d) happened last month, this morning, or one second ago. What is important is that the event in (d) is considered more relevant to the situation now than the event in (c), which is why it is given in the *present perfect*.

That said, let us consider the first sentence "I sent you a letter a few days ago, I was wondering if you have received it." Here the person who asks the question would seem interested to talk about what he or she wrote in the letter. (Lett. 'd' in my example.)

In the sentence "I sent you a letter a few days ago, I was wondering if you received it," the person who asks the question wants to make sure himself or herself that the letter is being received. (Lett. 'c' in my example.)

Comment: Great to see you around again, Carlo.

Comment: Although everything here looks to be true, it's got little to do with OP's question, which is about framing a question using auxiliary verbs *have* or *did*, not about framing a statement using past simple or present perfect. Whichever auxiliary verb OP uses implies nothing about the time of the thing being asked about, since it's explicitly stated that the French classes were ***today***.

Comment: This "answer" has been duplicated several times on EL&U see this [**answer**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/65866/44619) and this [**answer**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/62206/44619) too.

Comment: But in spoken American English, as far as I'm aware "I broke my glasses" while holding a pair of broken glasses would be completely normal.

Answer (score 3):

OP's friend has some odd ideas. It's true that there's an increasing tendency to use *to do* rather than *to have* as the "auxiliary verb" in such constructions (see [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20you%20eaten,did%20you%20eat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for the steady rise of *did you eat* over *have you eaten*), but it's a bit excessive to say *"Have you been [somewhere]"* is in any sense "old-fashioned".

---

One big difference between the two versions is replacing *today* with *yesterday* only works in one...

> *Have you been to French class yesterday? *(not valid English)*
>
> Did you go to French class yesterday? *(perfectly normal)*

(this difference is *totally irrelevant* to OP's exact context, which is explicitly about *earlier today*).

---

Another difference *in certain contexts* is *"have you been"* can be more "condemnatory"...

> "Have you been smoking cigarettes?" *normally sounds accusing/disapproving*
>
> "Did you smoke cigarettes?" *might be neutral, or even "incredulous/adulatory"*

(try replacing *"smoke cigarettes"* with *"kiss"* if that example doesn't work)

Comment: I don't think that Ngram tells you anything, except maybe that we are getting more obsessed about our diets. Nearly all of the hits for "did you eat" that I looked at were in constructions where the present perfect would never have been used.

Comment: +1 The trend to use the simple past for things that "have just happened" is far stronger in America than in England, I believe. So using each will give a different impression in either country.

Comment: @Peter: I'm not with you. What about [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+you+seen+them%2Cdid+you+see+them&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), comparing *"have you seen them"* and *"did you see them"*? I just think *do/did* is gradually on the rise as a "helper" verb, and that in some contexts it makes the term "present perfect" rather irrelevant.

Comment: @Cerberus: I think one of the main differences is that in the U.K., you generally use the present perfect with the adverbs "just" and "already", while in the U.S., you often use the simple past with these adverbs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *Do/did* is a red herring: this is really about the simple past v. the present perfect, isn't it? *I just finished my test* v. *I've just finished my test*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yeah exactly.

Comment: @Cerberus: Isn't the "simple past" in OP's context *"**Went** you to French class today?"*. That's certainly an archaic construction, but we have to indicate the interrogative mode somehow - usually using either *to have* or *to do* as a helper verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you're right here. Looking at a few verbs, the only one where the present perfect is gaining is ["sail"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+you+sail%2Chave+you+sailed&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=7).  And that must somehow be due to the advent of air travel.

Comment: @Cerberus: I think that's not "things that have just happened" in general, that's only the adverbs "just" and "already", which can work like the adverbial phrase "an hour ago" in the U.S. (and thus require the simple past).

Comment: @Cerberus: *“Have you been to the fair?”* may imply the fair is still going on, where “Did you go to the fair?” may imply it's over. But this only applies to the ***interrogative***. Neither *"I have been to the fair"* nor *"I went to the fair"* implies anything about whether it's still going on, except insofar as you might be less likely to tack *"last week"* on the end of the former. But OP's context is specifically ***today***, so even if that difference exists in principle, it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Peter: Hmm...so what about a situation where father comes home and asks his daughter where mother is. She answers: "Mom went to the mill to buy flour." I am guessing this is standard in America at least. I am suffering from semantic satiation at the moment, so I find it hard to say anything definite about the subject. But how about "Mom has gone to the mill to buy flour"? Is this used in America at all? How about England?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Umm now you are complicating things even further. First, *did she go?* and *she went* are both simple past. Interrogative or not doesn't change this. Secondly, you appear to be comparing apples and onions: *have you been* is about the verb *to be*, whereas *did you go?* is about *to go*. I use p.p. and s.p. intuitively, and I find the difference very hard to pin down. When I try to pick one consciously, I feel as though my brain shut down.

Comment: @Peter: Another, possibly-unrelated example for you both. I (have?) just typed this in the Linguistics.SE chat room: *Nobody has ever told me that!* I think *Nobody ever told me that!* is also acceptable, although I would not use that myself. But I feel that it may have a different meaning—then the next moment I feel that the latter just sounds American or something. I don't know any more. (I know, this isn't about "something that has just happened". By the way, somehow I don't feel like using *have* in the first sentence of this comment. Why not?)

Comment: @Cerberus: Gimmie a break! OP asks us to contrast *"Have you **been** to class?"* with *"Did you **go** to class?"*. But the core issue isn't about *to be/to go* - it's about any possible difference between using *did* or *have* as the auxiliary verb in order to frame a sentence asking about something in the past. I'm simply saying the only significant difference is the *have* form doesn't work for things far in the past, but that distinction is irrelevant in OP's context since we know the class was ***today***.

Comment: ...btw, if you write *"I have just typed"*, rather than *"I just typed"*, the present perfect serves to emphasis that the action was very recent. Which the word "just" does anyway, but such redundancy is perfectly normal, and there's nothing wrong with either version.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Um oh, oops! I was so busy considering p.s. v. p.p. that I ehm forgot to look at the question altogether. My brains are exploding (all six) so I think I should stop pondering this. Your analysis of the difference between *I have just typed* and *I just typed* has been noted.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion, it's more elegant to use "have been" sometimes, and I actually think it could come off as being more polite if you are talking with an acquaintance, co-worker, or stranger.  Using the past simple sounds a little more casual to me - not always, but sometimes.

I always liked using "have been"s in my sentences.  Habit, I guess.
But I did have some American teachers who frowned upon using it too much - especially in essay reports.  Especially this one teacher I had in high school.  You wouldn't believe how many times my sentences would be "corrected" by her, only to be reworded to be in the past simple form.  Come to think of it, I still don't know why she kept changing it.  Oh well.

Anyway, my point is, if your friend learned English mainly through school, she might think it's wrong or old-fashioned if she had teachers like mine and it's been ingrained in her head that she can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you "sound stupid" at all if you say that.

It's very common to use the Present Perfect (Have P.P.) when the period of time isn't finished or continues until now.

Have you seen Jim this morning? = asked at 10 am

Did you see Jim this morning? = asked at 1 pm

So, "Did you go to French class today?" in fact sounds to me like something a husband would ask his wife at night, right before they go to bed

Comment: From past until now is one use. The others are pre-present - "he has just left"; finished with present consequences - "he has learned to drive"; or indefinite past - "malaria has killed millions".

Comment: I think it's disingenuous to switch *today* in OP's sentences to *this morning*. The French class must be in the past in order to ask about it, but today is today all day long, so it can't be far in the past. Both OP's constructions do in fact occur, and I don't see either implies anything different from the other about how long ago the French class was. So I don't think the fact that such a distinction can be made in other contexts has any relevance here.

Comment: I see your point, Roaring Fish, FumbleFingers. The state of the Verb can in fact exist independent of the time expression. Like in the other threads then, it should be something about the current importance/ significance of the past action

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should add an interesting piece of information re: this morning with the Present Perfect and Simple Past.

Geoffrey Leech (2004) reports that there are some speakers of English who find it possible to say "I've been to the dentist this morning" in the afternoon or evening: "for them, it seems, we can interpret *this morning* as 'today in the morning.'"

Comment: I am certainly one of those speakers; do I gather that you would say *I'm going to the dentist this morning* and mean 'tomorrow in the morning'?  If so, it seems a peculiar use of *this*.

Comment: @TimLymington, no. I'd say "I went to the dentist this morning" unless I really want to emphasise the importance or relevance of my visit to the dentist.