# Have met vs. Met

Tags: grammar

there

They have met several times before.  vs.  They met several times before.

Could you please tell  the difference between the two sentences?

Thanks in advance!
 Burning the midnight oil,
Oodo

Comment: Please visit [ell.se] no need to burn midnight oil.

Comment: I seriously doubt if that original post would be of any avail to the OP. Folks, please be considerate towards new members.

Comment: This is a MUCH better duplicate [“I met” vs “I've met”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70509/i-met-vs-ive-met?rq=1)

Comment: And this question is very helpful too [Which is correct: “has died” or “died”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died) and finally this question:[When is the present perfect tense used instead of the past tense?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/when-is-the-present-perfect-tense-used-instead-of-the-past-tense)

Comment: If after reading the answers there is still some confusion, PLEASE edit your question explain what is confusing you, you can quote directly from the answers posted. Then your question *might* be reopened. I do hope these links will help you.