# Why people use past tense when talking about something always true

Tags: tenses

Examples:
*xxx was the founder of ...*
*xxx was the first ...*

This does not limit to living person/person passed away, but also items.

To me the status of *the first*, *the founder of* etc. does not change and stays there forever. Its always true.

Something that changes e.g. *yyy was the fastest computer* makes more sense as the fastest can be replaced with something more modern.

Comment: Might duplicate [What tense to use for a dead person's permanent contributions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56471) or  [When is the present perfect tense used instead of the past tense?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1357), or  [Simple past or present perfect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/62190), etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tense to use for a dead person's permanent contributions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56471/what-tense-to-use-for-a-dead-persons-permanent-contributions)

Comment: I asked because of the very same reason that your linked answer tells us: both are used...and I am asking here, WHY? Because to me, that is always true. How does it make sense in the English context to use past tense to describe something always true?

Comment: @curiousdannii I think user has a point. The virtually one word answer to the other question was *both*. This questions asks why the past is possible.

Comment: The dead/alive thing is a red herring, as (I think) the OP says (although I'm not 100% sure I'm interpreting that sentence that ends with "but also items" correctly). "Roger Bannister **was** the first person to run a 4-minute mile" (and he's still with us). I think it's because the event that's being talked about was in the past.

Comment: Going to the OP's "but, why?": the dead/alive thing has some bearing, but it's not the complete story. In English, we can't apply "is" to someone who has died, because that person "isn't" anymore. Consider: "George Washington *is* the first President of the United States" is ungrammatical because while the fact is eternal, GW isn't.

Comment: Thank you guys. Then in that sense, we are introducing ambiguity between historical events and fact that no longer holds unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

The past tense is used because the events involved were in the past.

> "William the Conqueror was the first Norman king of England"

is grammatically correct because he was king in the past, even though the statement will always be true.

However,

> "Hilary Clinton will be the first female President"

is also grammatically correct, because the event of her becoming President is in the future. After her presidency had ended, it would become "Hilary Clinton **was** the first female President". So "Barack Obama **is** the first African-American president."

Comment: Minor (but pertinent) correction: immediately after she is inaugurated, and for at least the following four years (presuming no interruption in her office), we will say "Hillary Clinton *is* the first female president". Then, unless she is re-elected, we will switch to using  "was".

Comment: I agree "was" is used because of the past event, but on the other hand that is simply neglecting the always true fact. Is there a rule here, e.g. the tense follows the subject? If thats true, how about a swapped version: "The first Norman king of England IS William the Conqueror"?

Comment: @Dan - Agreed and edited :) And user, the sentence has the same meaning and grammaticality regardless of the order of "William the Conqueror" and "the first Norman king of England"; both are in the past. (If one was in the past and one in the present, how could they be the same?)